# Product inventory database

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, sql-injection

I just finished writing a program which working with a database. Throughout the process when working with people to get past some of the hurdles I faced I was ridiculed for my SQL statements. I have never fully understand what to do to protect myself and I know there is a lot of information out there to read. But now that I have a working program all done with PDO would someone mind showing me what I can do to make myself more secure. I would like to produce the most professional code I can.

File One, Drops a table if it exist then creates a new table. Opens a file and inserts the csv file into the database.

```
      try {
      $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
      $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " . $table_name;
      $dbh->query($sql);

      $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $table_name . " (
      id int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      wuno_product varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_description varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_alternates varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_onhand varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_condition varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;"; 
          $dbh->query($sql);

        file_put_contents( $csv_file, preg_replace( "@(\r\n),@", ',', file_get_contents( $csv_file ) ) );
    if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
           fgetcsv($handle);   
           while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                  $col[$c] = $data[$c];
                }

         $col1 = $col[0];
         $col2 = $col[1];
         $col3 = $col[2];
         $col4 = $col[3];
         $col5 = $col[4];

        // SQL Query to insert data into DataBase
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table_name . "(wuno_product, wuno_description, wuno_alternates, wuno_onhand, wuno_condition) 
        VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."')";
        $dbh->query( $sql );
        }
        fclose($handle);
        }
        if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
        }
        else{
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
        }
        $dbh = null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }  

 }
```

File 2, Loads the paginated the total table from the database.

```
   $limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 5;
    $offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
    try {
      $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    if (count($results) > 0) {
      foreach ($results as $res) {
        echo '<tr class="invent">';  
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_product'] . '</td>';  
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_alternates'] . '</td>';  
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_description'] . '</td>';  
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_onhand'] . '</td>';  
        echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_condition'] . '</td>';  
        echo '</tr>';   
      }
    }
```

File 3, Handles the search query displaying the paginated data to the user when they search,

```
<?php
require_once ('Dbconfig.php');

$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 5;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

if(!empty($_POST["itemID"])) {
 $sql=" SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE wuno_product like '%". $_POST["itemID"] ."%' OR wuno_alternates like '%". $_POST["itemID"] ."%' ORDER BY wuno_product ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ";
try {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<tr class="invent">';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_product'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_alternates'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_description'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_onhand'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_condition'] . '</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';   
  }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Injection**

Your code is completely open to SQL injection.

It is not enough to simply use `prepare`. The important part is that you should **never put variables directly into the query**. The query should only contain placeholders (either `:key` or `?`). The variables are then later bound to the query.

You have variables in most of your queries, for example:

```
// $limit and $offset are user controlled:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
$sql=" SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE wuno_product like '%". $_POST["itemID"] ."%' OR wuno_alternates like '%". $_POST["itemID"] ."%' ORDER BY wuno_product ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ";
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table_name . "(wuno_product, wuno_description, wuno_alternates, wuno_onhand, wuno_condition) 
    VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."')";
```

You can see a correct usage of prepared statements in the [documentation of PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

**Misc**

- your indention is off, making your code really hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. The answer to this question is important to me. I would really appreciate an answer and example based on my exact situation. If you do find the time to help me with this please know your effort really will make a huge difference to me. Thank you,

Comment: @wuno Did you click the link "Documentation of PDO"? It contains exactly the examples you are looking for.